# Free / Open Source Multiprocessor OS

Tags: gratis

I want to know what are the freely available multiprocessor (physical multiple processors) OS available.

I know there are some Linux / Unix variants but don't know any specific one.

Preferably the specific OS with a download link.

Purpose: To experiment with multiple Raspberry Pi clusters to do parallel computation jobs. (e.g. http://www.mersenne.org/)

If possible also suggest some links of POCs for this kind of project.

Comment: You should be more specific about your needs/goals. Are you looking to use multiple computers to split a large task in to a bunch of sub-tasks to be completed separately? Is so, you need an implementation of [grid computing](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grid_computing) rather than a specific operating system.

Comment: @Basil: My need is to make a small replica of a supercomputer which can be scaled by plugging in more units of Rpi.

Comment: I suspect you will need to get much more specific about what you mean, to get any helpful answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are actually asking for the wrong thing - you are actually looking for "Cluster Computing" or "Distributed Processing" - and Rasbperrian already supports this sort of processing via python and [dispy](http://dispy.sourceforge.net/) or numerous other frameworks.

Answer (score 0):

> I know there are some Linux / Unix variants but don't know any
>   specific one

In general all Linux distros share the same kernel. The main differences are the applications installed as standard and the desktop manager.  Just ask at https://unix.stackexchange.com/ "Does  support multi-procssor".

Don't bother. [I looked up the documentation for it](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/installation-guide/i386/ch02s01.html)

> 2.1.4. Multiple Processors
>
> Multiprocessor support — also called “symmetric multiprocessing” or
>   SMP — is available for this architecture. The standard Ubuntu 16.04
>   kernel image has been compiled with SMP-alternatives support. This
>   means that the kernel will detect the number of processors (or
>   processor cores) and will automatically deactivate SMP on uniprocessor
>   systems.